# How do I read 上 in ご注文の際は予めそちらをご了承の上お願い致します? What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, pronunciation

> ご注文の際は予めそちらをご了承の**上**お願い致します。

How do I read the 上? うえ? or じょう?
What is the meaning of 上 in that sentence?

Comment: @macraf I don't know. My japanese is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「上」 is read 「うえ」 in that context.

「～～の上（で）」 means "***based on*** ~~".  The ~~ part acts as a premise or condition in performing an action.  The ~~ part usually describes an understanding or agreement of some sort.

> 「ご[注文]{ちゅうもん}の[際]{さい}は[予]{あらかじ}めそちらをご[了承]{りょうしょう}の[上]{うえ}お[願]{ねが}い[致]{いた}します。」
>
> = "Please place orders upon agreement and acceptance of (what has already been explained)."

Comment: What does そちら refer to?

Comment: そ{so}ち{chi}ら{ra} here refers to "those, those things over there" -- in other words, something previously referred to, perhaps a list of conditions displayed elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

うえ=on.In english,after～ condition～ understanding～ on～(this is best similiar word to　上).ご了承の下（もと）is same meaning.

Comment: そちら"を"ご了承の上 is correct.

Answer (score -1):

The reading of 上 in this case is うえ and it means "after" in this case.

ご了承の上 is translated as " after agreement".

Comment: What does the entire sentence mean?

Comment: I think it is translated as " When you order, would you order after agreement of them in advance." The "them" are like contract sheet.